# StackExchange.Redis SetAdd behavior

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm currently using the StackExchange.Redis.

I'm just wondering about the behavior of SetAdd. I have an array of RedisValue, during debugging mode, I could see the expected order of my array but when the SetAdd fires, it seems that the stored array has been shuffled.

What's the right command for me to store the correct order of my array?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A `set`is not an `array`. Read the redis documentation on data types [here](https://redis.io/topics/data-types).

A Redis Set is an unordered collection of strings, with no duplication allowed.

So if you need to maintain an order or an index, you should use a different data type, like [List](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#lists) or [Sorted Set](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#sorted-sets)